# how to disabled the core module completely (Frontend)

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I want to disabled the `Mage_Checkout` completely. but when i disabled the `adavnced > modules` it shows blank page not 404 page. when i disabled the from `etc/modules` it show errors of dependent module. any other solution

Comment: So.....you want magento ecommerce without the ecommerce part?

Comment: @ProxiBlue yes it's requirement maybe enable it later but now want this

Comment: this may be of use/help, if not use-able fully, but for the 'how' https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewrite the controller in my case `Mage_Checkout`

```
<routers>
        <checkout>
        <args>
            <modules>
            <Spacename_Modulename before="Mage_Checkout">Spacename_Modulename</Spacename_Modulename> 
            </modules>
        </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
```

in controller add `preDispatch` and just add `$this->norouteAction();`

```
public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();
         $this->norouteAction();

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable `Mage_Checkout` module through activation file (ie `app\etc\modules`) and remove all dependencies from other modules manually. You can achieve this by removing dependencies through activation files of other modules. Other than that, there is no other solutions in my knowledge.

Still you can expect some errors from other modules due to the lack of `Mage_Checkout` module since Magento core modules are not independent modules. There should be some unavoidable dependency in other modules. In those cases, you need to remove or replace such dependencies from other modules too. You can expect such dependencies in layout xml files or in some block or in some models.

Comment: as i already mention there is long list of module's. so can't do that.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Yes. But you can avoid direct dependencies through activation files of those modules which are dependent on `Mage_Checkout` modules that will remove most of the errors. But removing Mage_Checkout module completely from the system is very hard. I remember which is mentioned by Marius once. He faced this issue while he convert Magento to a blog tool (CMS).

Comment: thanks but I ending up doing set the 404 page for these.. that will fulfill the requirement.